# Regex for tagging UPPERCASE CAUTION data

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++, regex-greedy

Fellow Forum Members,

I'm using NotePad++ and have a bunch of CAUTIONS embedded within other text data. The two constants that set the CAUTION data apart from the rest of the text data are two factors. One is the CAUTION text is always in UPPERCASE text and the second is the CAUTION text always starts with the word "CAUTION" in uppercase.  Below is a small example of what I'm descibing:

Bla bla bla bla bla. CAUTION DO NOT PERFORM MAINTENANCE ON MACHINE WITHOUT FIRST READING THE OWNER'S MANUAL. Bla bla bla bla bla bla.

Is it possible for a RegEx to find many different variations of the text below:

CAUTION DO NOT PERFORM MAINTENANCE ON MACHINE WITHOUT FIRST READING THE OWNER'S MANUAL.

And then replace it with the following:

```
 <caution><para>DO NOT PERFORM MAINTENANCE ON MACHINE WITHOUT FIRST READING THE OWNER'S MANUAL.</para></caution>
```

I need help coding a RegEx that does the following:

1. Is able to target data that always starts with the word "CAUTION" (in UPPERCASE)
2. Is able to target all of the UPPERCASE text that follows the word "CAUTION" until it changes over to lowercase text.
3. Deletes the word "CAUTION" located at the beginning after XML tag is added.
4. Won't be fooled by the UPPERCASE "B" in the word "Bla" (i.e. "MANUAL. Bla").
   In other words, it doesn't include in the find result the first capital letter that begins the next sentence. How can this greedy concern be eliminated?

Is such a RegEx possible? How in the world can a RegEx be made smart enough to just find only CAUTION related text based on what I have described?  Any info will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have notpad++ specifically, so notwithstanding any quirks in their regex implementation, this seems to do the trick:

```
CAUTION ([A-Z](([^a-z])+\s+)+)
```

with a replacement of

```
<caution><para>$1</caution></para>
```

See it in action here:

http://regexr.com?35mku

Comment: Nice and this captures trailing punctuation, +1